# Error #1009: when listening to a button that exists on stage as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm developing a game using as3. It is my first time using flash and as3. 
My problem is that I have a button "callBasket" exists on stage, and it's an instance of a class called "CallMethod" my code is as follows:

```
public class SweetBasket extends Basket{

    var basketButtonSweet:BasketButtonSweet = new BasketButtonSweet;

    public function SweetBasket() {

    }

    override protected function clickButton (event:MouseEvent):void{
        stage.addChild(basketButtonSweet);
        basketButtonSweet.x = 547;
        basketButtonSweet.y = 162;
        basket = "sweet";
        call = stage.getChildByName("callBasket") as CallMethod;

        call.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);// here is my problem

    }



    protected function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
        clicked = true;
        trace(clicked);
    }
```

And this is my Basket clas, although I don't think it matters.

```
public class Basket extends SimpleButton{

    var basketButton:BasketButton;
    var basket:String;
    var call:CallMethod;
    public var clicked:Boolean = new Boolean(false);


    public function Basket() {

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickButton);

    }



    protected function clickButton (event:MouseEvent):void{


    }
```

using addEventListener gives me an error

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. 
>     at OOPGame::SweetBasket/clickButton()

Any idea why is this error happening and what have I done wrong?

Comment: Is the CallMethod class something you've made yourself? Can you explain what it does?

Comment: yes I've made it, and it turned out the problem is that it doesn't do anything. Thanks for spending time reading and commenting. I don't know how I didn't figure this out earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It pretty much looks like callBasket" does not exist on stage(/is placed somewhere else but not on stage directly). To make sure it really exists, add a trace after "call = stage.getChildByName("callBasket") as CallMethod;" trace("call exists: " + call); what does the trace state?

Comment: This is what I got, "call exists: null". Where else can it be other than on stage and how can I find out where is it placed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like element is simply not added to the stage. Check the code fragment where you add element with name "callBasket". Also check that "callBasket" is instance of class CallMethod (or it's inheritor).

Comment: callBasket is added manually to stage, and I'm very sure it is an instance of CallMethod as this is the first thing I thought of.

Comment: Can you show code, where you added it? Also, it maybe problem that you added callBasket after you try get it.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I meant that the callBasket button is on stage I dragged it from library. Thank you for trying to help, but I figured something else that saved me the above trouble.